How to create a cylinder that can be deformed in a gaussian way?
I have tried recreating a cylinder that is deformed in a gaussian way. I will need to create deformed cylinders in a relatively simple way, since I will be using them as input for a genetic algorithm. I can also add to that the deformations only should go along the vertical direction.
Here's my code for the deformed cylinder generation:
import pyvista as pv
import numpy as np

# Set higher resolution for a finer mesh
height = 2.0
radius = 1.0
resolution_height = 50  # Number of subdivisions along the height
resolution_circumference = 200  # Number of subdivisions along the circumference

# Create a structured cylinder with finer mesh
cylinder = pv.CylinderStructured(radius=radius, height=height,
                                 theta_resolution=resolution_circumference,
                                 z_resolution=resolution_height)

# Convert the structured grid to PolyData for normal computation
cylinder_polydata = cylinder.extract_surface()

# Compute normals for the surface
cylinder_polydata = cylinder_polydata.compute_normals(cell_normals=False)

# Extract the computed point normals
normals = cylinder_polydata['Normals']

# Define different standard deviations for radial and vertical directions
num_parameters = 5  # Adjust as needed

deformed_points = np.copy(cylinder_polydata.points)

# Generate random sigmas for radial direction
sigmas = np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.5, size=num_parameters)  # Example range for sigmas
sgns_scale = np.random.uniform(-3, -2, size=num_parameters)
centers = np.random.uniform(-height, height, size=num_parameters)

for sgn, sigma, center in zip(sgns_scale, sigmas, centers):
    for i, point in enumerate(deformed_points):
        distance = np.linalg.norm(point - np.array([ center, 0, 0]))  # Distance from the center
        gaussian_factor = np.exp(-0.5 * (distance / sigma) ** 2)  # Gaussian weight
        displacement = sgn * gaussian_factor * normals[i]  # Displacement vector
        deformed_points[i] += displacement

# Update the cylinder's points with the deformed points
deformed_cylinder = pv.PolyData(deformed_points, faces=cylinder_polydata.faces)

# Create a plotter object
plotter = pv.Plotter()

# Add original and merged cylinders to the plotter
plotter.add_mesh(deformed_cylinder, color='blue', label='Deformed Cylinder', show_edges=True)

# Add points (nodes) to visualize the mesh structure
plotter.add_points(deformed_cylinder.points, color='red', point_size=5, render_points_as_spheres=True, label='Deformed Nodes')

# Add a legend to the plotter
plotter.add_legend()

# Show the plot with the mesh
plotter.show()

In doing so, I get a cylinder that is deformed:

However, the cylinder isn't capped, and it only contains the surface.
I would like to create a closed mesh instead, so I tried using the pv.Cylinder() instead of pv.CylinderStructured(). But the issue here is that the mesh lines only go vertically, and I need mesh lines that go along the polar direction.
So the result looks a bit off:

I tried creating a triangular mesh but then these gaussian deformations sometimes happen to deform the caps of the cylinder and creates all sorts of weird shapes.
Is there any way to seal off the CylinderStructured() mesh by capping the top and bottom after the deformation? I think that would be the easiest route namely, in that way we can avoid deformations of the caps to the cylinder. Or is there any other efficient way to do this?

You wrote "However, the cylinder isn't capped, and it only contains the surface" which sounds like you actually want a space-filling 3d mesh, but the rest of your posts reads as you looking for a PolyData surface that encloses a cylinder. Which is it?

@AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні  I am sorry for the confusion. Yes, I basically want a space-filling 3d mesh.

I'm not going to post an answer because I don't know how to make your deformations 2d, and it's not at all clear to me what you expect for your space-filling case because your above example is a 2d shell. But anyway you can get your 3d mesh with pv.CylinderStructured(radius=np.linspace(0, max_radius, resolution_radius).cast_to_unstructured_grid().clean(1e-8) or similar. For the deformation you have to adjust your code so that your displacements are always perpendicular to the cylindrical axis. Might have to amend normals to get a sane result. As I said, unclear, and I can't investiagte now.

It is really hard to see what the problem is without the code that creates the problem.  We are only seeing the code that gives an almost desired output.  It is also unknown what is desired as the outcome.  For example, the pv.Cylinder is three pieces - a cylindrical shell, and two end caps.  One solution could be to manually add the end caps of the existing code as posted.

It will be better to form your own PolyData directly with points and cell connectivity.  You will have full control.  This is if you want to define the volume as enclosed by a 2D surface containing 2D cells, e.g. triangles.  You would want to define a UnstructuredGrid if you want to define a 3D volume directly with 3D cells, e.g. tetrahedrons.
